# Selecting unique values using user input

Tags: r

I want to select unique values based on user selection from the column header. This is currently under my reactive function.

Example:

```
Name    Income    Last Name
John    20        Smith
Sally   44        Smith
John    32        Gold
```

So there's 2 Johns.

I want something like this:

```
selItems <- c(input$fromUser, "Income")
unique(selItems$input$fromUser) #totally not correct but this is what I am looking to do
```

As you can see the user can select all Last names that is unique too. So for all Smiths, how much do they make?

Desired Output
if user selects `Name`

```
John 52
Sally 44
```

or if user selects `Last Name`, then:

```
Smith 64
Gold  32
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you are looking to do some form of aggregation rather than removing duplicates. You have to tell R how to combine redundant rows. The easiest way to do with would be with aggregate. here's an example. First, a more reproducible version of your sample input

```
dd<-read.table(text="Name    Income    LastName
John    20        Smith
Sally   44        Smith
John    32        Gold", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Then you can use `reformualte` to build the formulas for use with `aggregate()`

```
sel<-"Name"
aggregate(reformulate(sel, "Income"), dd, sum)
#    Name Income
# 1  John     52
# 2 Sally     44    

sel<-"LastName"
aggregate(reformulate(sel, "Income"), dd, sum)
#   LastName Income
# 1     Gold     32
# 2    Smith     64
```

Comment: this is great! Thank you so much. What if i have more than just income I'd like to sum? Im reading the doc, doesn't say if multiple response is okay? I tried with a list didn't work.

Comment: You could do it by `cbind()`-ing terms in the response of the formula, but at that point you're probably be better off using dplyr's `group_by()` and `summarize()`.

Answer (score 1):

Early attempt, using `dplyr`:

```
dat <- data.frame(Name = c("John","Sally", "John"),
                  Income = c(20, 44, 32),
                  LastName = c("Smith", "Smith", "Gold"),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
library(dplyr)
```

I'll assume that `input` is a list provided by some interface such as `shiny`.

This first batch does no summarizing, just a simple "first record":

```
input <- list(fromUser = "Name")
dat %>%
  group_by_(input$fromUser) %>%
  slice(1)
# Source: local data frame [2 x 3]
# Groups: Name [2]
#    Name Income LastName
#   <chr>  <dbl>    <chr>
# 1  John     20    Smith
# 2 Sally     44    Smith

input <- list(fromUser = "LastName")
dat %>%
  group_by_(input$fromUser) %>%
  slice(1)
# Source: local data frame [2 x 3]
# Groups: LastName [2]
#    Name Income LastName
#   <chr>  <dbl>    <chr>
# 1  John     32     Gold
# 2  John     20    Smith
```

If you want something different, insert a sort or max or sum or such:

```
input <- list(fromUser = "LastName")
dat %>%
  group_by_(input$fromUser) %>%
  summarize(Income = sum(Income))
# # A tibble: 2 x 2
#   LastName Income
#      <chr>  <dbl>
# 1     Gold     32
# 2    Smith     64
```

Answer (score 0):

Just saw the desired output you would like, here is some updated code for that:

```
NameArray<-data.frame(Name= c("John", "Sally", "John"), Income = c(20,44,32), LastName = c("Smith", "Smith","Gold"))

IncomeArray<-function(SearchColumn,SearchText){ 
    #Name of column, Persons name/income.
    dims<-which(NameArray[,deparse(substitute(SearchColumn))]==deparse(substitute(SearchText)))
    print(NameArray[dims,names(NameArray)!=(deparse(substitute(SearchColumn)))])
}

IncomeArray(Name,John) #Search 'Name' column for 'John' and print out corresponding information.

   Income LastName
1     20    Smith
3     32     Gold
```

I have left the original code below for completeness

```
NameArray<-data.frame(Name= c("John", "Sally", "John"), Income = c(20,44,32), LastName = c("Smith", "Smith","Gold"))

IncomeArray<-function(SearchColumn,SearchText, ResultColumn){ 
   #Name of column, Persons name/income, Column name of information of interest.
    dims<-which(NameArray[,deparse(substitute(SearchColumn))]==deparse(substitute(SearchText)))
    print(NameArray[dims,deparse(substitute(ResultColumn))])
}

IncomeArray(Name,John,Income) #Search 'Name' column for 'John' and print out each 'John''s income.
[1] 20 32
```

The above function might help you out in the cases where you have all the information and just need to access the required columns - little basic but it gets the job done.